# Eclipse cannot find Android Phone

Tags: adb, android

I recently upgraded my android version from 2.2.3 to 2.3.5 (HTC Desire HD), and now eclipse cannot find it, I had no problems prior. I had no problems before. USB debugging is enabled, and my connection type is on charge only (have tried disk drive too). Restarting the computer did nothing, nor did restarting eclipse. I have also done a factory data reset many times. I am on windows 7.

Any ideas/Know what the problem is?

Thanks.

Comment: try updating device drivers. just a thought.

Comment: Try reinstalling the drivers. Do you see the ADB driver listed on the bottom right of your screen? Also try `adb kill-server` then `adb devices` on your command prompt

Comment: In device manager, I have a 'HTC Android Phone USB Device'. If I enable USB debugging, I also get a 'Android Device' with a missing driver. Looking on the HTC website, I cannot find an OEM driver for it, perhaps I am looking wrong.

Comment: I see nothing about a driver on eclipse/windows (not sure what your referring to), as for the command prompt. 'adb' commands have never worked for me, they are unrecognized.

Comment: download and install `HTC Sync` in your pc

Comment: Ok, I am downloading HTC Sync, I have also added the 'adb' to my command prompt. 'adb devices' lists nothing under 'list of devices attached'

Comment: HTC Sync solved my problem, Thank you. Would you post that as an answer, or shall I?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer courtesy of 'Samir Mangroliya':

--> Download and install HTC Sync in your pc.

Downloading HTC Sync installed the necessary drivers to my computer.

Answer (score -1):

Connect your phone to computer before starting Eclipse.